# Equivalence relations - countability

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, transcendental-numbers

The equivalence relation $\sim$ on the set of transcendental $X$ is defined by the following property:

$x\sim y$ if and only if $x-y\in \mathbb{Q} $.

Now the set $Y$ is the set of equivalence classes generated by $\sim$. 
How do we know that a particular equivalence class $[x]$ is countable?

Comment: Hint: $[x] = \{ z \mid \exists q \in \Bbb{Q}\cdot z = x + q\}$.

Comment: Typing note: `$~$` is used to increase space between objects while `\!` is used to decrease space between objects.  E.g. `$1~~~2\!3$` produces $1~~~2\!3$.  To have the symbol `~` appear as a symbol, use instead `$\sim$` to produce $\sim$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $a$ is a representative of the class $[x]$, then observe that
$$
[x]=\{a+q : q\in\mathbb Q\}.
$$
Hence $|[x]|=\aleph_0$.